# Getting invalid array key error on condition which should have been previously handled

Tags: php

I am having some issues with some code.
Its hard to say exactly what is causing the issue so apologies if the title is inaccurate.

So I am parsing returned JSON data.
Now the `salary` will always be one of the following formats

£00000/annum /hour / day

£NEG

or empty value

Here is my code :

```
if(!empty($jobs['salary']))
        {
            if(strpos($jobs['salary'],'Neg'||'NEG' !== false))
            { 
            $salary = 'Negotiable';
            $salarytype = '';  
            } 
            else 
            {
            $chunks = preg_split('/(\/hour|\/annum|\/day)/', $jobs['salary'],-1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
            $salarya = $chunks[0];//.' '.str_replace('/','per ',$chunks[1]);
            $salary = str_replace('£','&pound;',$salarya);
            $salarytype = str_replace('/',' per ',$chunks[1]);
            }
        } else {            
        $salary = 'Not Specified';
        $salarytype = '';
        }
    
echo $salary.''.$salarytype.'<br>';
```

Now here is some of the data once formatted and displayed

The per annum / hour or day works fine

Junior Infrastructure Engineer
£25000 - £28000 per annum

The empty value works fine

Finance Systems Analyst
Not Specified

Yet the Neg or NEG is where it throws an issue

```
Warning: Undefined array key 1 in /test.php on line 84

Deprecated: str_replace(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($subject) of type array|string is deprecated in /test.php on line 84
£NEG
```

This is line 84

```
$salarytype = str_replace('/',' per ',$chunks[1]);
```

Anyone able to shed some light on what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: What does `$chunks` contain in that case? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue
Didn't properly format the initial strpos check
Changed to this and works fine

```
  if((strpos($jobs['salary'],'Neg')|| strpos($jobs['salary'],'NEG') || strpos($jobs['salary'],'NEGOTIABLE') || strpos($jobs['salary'],'Negotiable')) !== false)
```

Comment: strpos returns the position of the found element (including 0 if at the front) or false if not found. For the other checks you also have to compare with `!== false`, not just the last one. See [PHP: strpos documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: The above answer I posted works perfectly and it doesn't just check the last one

Comment: Well you `||` the result of each strpos together and check if the resulting boolean is `!== false`. But you have to compare each `strpos` result to `!== false` instead. Remember that strpos returns 0 if the found text is at the first character index (starting at 0). 0 evaluates to false. In that case `(strpos(...) || strpos(...)) !== false` will evaluate to false even though the text was found. Probably just doesn't happen in your exact data set but I had to mention it.